# WordPress SFTP Upgrade Not Working: "Could not copy file"

Tags: wordpress, sftp, lamp

I am running on a very secure LAMP server that requires me to use SFTP instead of regular ftp. I use the "SSH SFTP Updater Support" Plugin in order to make this work.

When prompted with the connection information screen, I enter in my host name, username, and password, and select "SSH2" for a connection type.

When updating WordPress itself OR plugins from the WordPress admin and entering all my credentials, it appears to be working fine. The page tells me that it's downloading the update, then unpacking the update.

Then it simply says "Could not copy file. folder/filename.php". From what I can tell, this is just the very first file it attempts to copy. Nothing gets copied.

It does this even when I change permissions to 777 for the folder or file (or both) that it is updating.

I assume it's something server related, as we just hardened our server security. But the thing is, I can connect via SFTP with an FTP client just fine. I've heard maybe the host name should be different since it's the server interacting with itself, but I don't know what I would change it to. Any thoughts?

Comment: it could be the ownership issue on the folder(s).  Depending on your server settings this may vary.  Is the SFTP user part of the correct group that has rights to the folder?

Comment: It's the exact same SFTP user that I use from my FTP clients, both Filezilla and Dreamweaver. And it works fine from there.